# Finding the CDF from a PDF with two variables

Tags: probability, statistics

The random variable $X$ has probability density function (PDF):

$$f(x\mid\beta) = \beta x^{−(\beta+1))}$$

$ x > 1$, $\beta > 0$

Find the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of $X$

This is the PDF I have been given. Usually if I were to generate the CDF from this, I would make a dummy variable, probably replacing the $x$ and integrate from $1$ to $x.$ But this case I cant seem to figure out as there seems to be two variables, so I am unsure in the difference of methods? Do I do two separate integrations making each a dummy variable at one time? If so how would I go about this?

Any help and questions for further clarification is a appreciated!

Comment: Here $\beta$ is a fixed parameter, the only variable is $x$. So to get the pdf you need to integrate with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 2):

$\beta$ is a parameter.

The CDF can be computed as $$F_X(x\mid\beta) =\int_1^x \beta t^{-(\beta+1)}\,dt $$

Answer (score 0):

Your density is the one of a [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution). In the enclosed link you will find your result which is easy to get simply integrating $f_X$.